# Dovecot quota - infinite loop when mailbox full

Tags: email-server, dovecot, quota

We get an infinite loop once quota is exceeded.

Having set up the dovecot quota as per https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/quota/

Here are the parameters I modified (my setup was working with no concern):

```
90-quota.conf
plugin {
    quota = maildir:User quota
    quota_rule = *:storage=100MB
    # 10% of 1GB = 100MB
    quota_rule2 = Trash:storage=+10%%
    # 20% of 1GB = 200MB
    quota_rule3 = Spam:storage=+20%%
    quota_max_mail_size = 30M

# Quota messages incl. user is no longer over quota
quota_warning   = storage=90%% quota-warning 95 %u %d
quota_warning2  = storage=80%% quota-warning 90 %u %d
quota_warning3 = -storage=100%% quota-warning below %u %d
#quota_exceeded_message = ERROR:422 - Mailbox full
}
  
service quota-warning {
  executable = script /var/mail/quota-warning.sh
  # use some unprivileged user for executing the quota warnings
  unix_listener quota-warning {
      user = mail


  }
}
```

With a script, that I did make inoperant by commenting the lines, hence the error does not come from the script actions:

```
quota-warning.sh 
#!/bin/sh
PERCENT=$1
USER=$2
DOMAIN=$3
#cat << EOF | /usr/libexec/dovecot/dovecot-lda -d $USER -o "plugin/quota=maildir:User quota:noenforcing"
#From: postmaster@bogo.ovh
#Subject: quota warning
#Your mailbox is now $PERCENT% full.
#EOF
```

Here is what the output of `journalctl -f -u postfix -u dovecot` (CentOS):

```
ept. 29 15:40:22 mail.domain.net systemd[1]: Starting Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server...
sept. 29 15:40:22 mail.domain.net dovecot[807534]: master: Dovecot v2.3.16 (7e2e900c1a) starting up for imap, pop3, lmtp
sept. 29 15:40:22 mail.domain.net systemd[1]: Started Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server.
sept. 29 15:40:39 mail.domain.net auth[807553]: pam_sss(dovecot:auth): authentication success; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=dovecot ruser=comm rhost=192.168.1.30 user=comm
sept. 29 15:40:40 mail.domain.net dovecot[807537]: imap-login: Login: user=<comm>, method=PLAIN, rip=192.168.1.30, lip=192.168.1.20, mpid=807557, TLS, session=<r5W3eSLN+K4KCAAD>
sept. 29 15:40:50 mail.domain.net postfix/submission/smtpd[807564]: initializing the server-side TLS engine
sept. 29 15:40:50 mail.domain.net postfix/submission/smtpd[807564]: connect from unknown[192.168.1.30]
sept. 29 15:40:50 mail.domain.net postfix/submission/smtpd[807564]: setting up TLS connection from unknown[192.168.1.30]
sept. 29 15:40:50 mail.domain.net postfix/submission/smtpd[807564]: unknown[192.168.1.30]: TLS cipher list "aNULL:-aNULL:HIGH:MEDIUM:+RC4:@STRENGTH"
sept. 29 15:40:50 mail.domain.net postfix/submission/smtpd[807564]: SSL_accept:before SSL initialization
sept. 29 15:40:50 mail.domain.net postfix/submission/smtpd[807564]: SSL_accept:before SSL initialization
sept. 29 15:40:50 mail.domain.net postfix/submission/smtpd[807564]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS read client hello
sept. 29 15:40:50 mail.domain.net postfix/submission/smtpd[807564]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS write server hello
sept. 29 15:40:50 mail.domain.net postfix/submission/smtpd[807564]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS write change cipher spec
sept. 29 15:40:50 mail.domain.net postfix/submission/smtpd[807564]: SSL_accept:TLSv1.3 write encrypted extensions
sept. 29 15:40:50 mail.domain.net postfix/submission/smtpd[807564]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS write certificate
sept. 29 15:40:50 mail.domain.net postfix/submission/smtpd[807564]: SSL_accept:TLSv1.3 write server certificate verify
sept. 29 15:40:50 mail.domain.net postfix/submission/smtpd[807564]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS write finished
sept. 29 15:40:50 mail.domain.net postfix/submission/smtpd[807564]: SSL_accept:TLSv1.3 early data
sept. 29 15:40:50 mail.domain.net postfix/submission/smtpd[807564]: SSL_accept:TLSv1.3 early data
sept. 29 15:40:50 mail.domain.net postfix/submission/smtpd[807564]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS read finished
sept. 29 15:40:50 mail.domain.net postfix/submission/smtpd[807564]: unknown[192.168.1.30]: Issuing session ticket, key expiration: 1632924649
sept. 29 15:40:50 mail.domain.net postfix/submission/smtpd[807564]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
sept. 29 15:40:50 mail.domain.net postfix/submission/smtpd[807564]: Anonymous TLS connection established from unknown[192.168.1.30]: TLSv1.3 with cipher TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (128/128 bits) key-exchange X25519 server-signature RSA-PSS (2048 bits) server-digest SHA256
sept. 29 15:40:51 mail.domain.net auth[807553]: pam_sss(dovecot:auth): authentication success; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=dovecot ruser=comm rhost=192.168.1.30 user=comm
sept. 29 15:40:52 mail.domain.net postfix/submission/smtpd[807564]: B898A7F9E7C: client=unknown[192.168.1.30], sasl_method=PLAIN, sasl_username=comm
sept. 29 15:40:53 mail.domain.net postfix/cleanup[807516]: B898A7F9E7C: message-id=<c650f17b-5d64-dac4-1760-96e8ccc0e455@domain.net>
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/qmgr[807513]: B898A7F9E7C: from=<comm@domain.net>, size=829, nrcpt=2 (queue active)
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net dovecot[807537]: lmtp(807580): Connect from local
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net dovecot[807537]: lmtp(807581): Connect from local
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net dovecot[807537]: lmtp(james)<807581><AkBAEedsVGGdUgwAgoIkEA>: sieve: msgid=<c650f17b-5d64-dac4-1760-96e8ccc0e455@domain.net>: failed to store into mailbox 'INBOX': Quota exceeded (mailbox for user is full)
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net dovecot[807537]: lmtp(james)<807581><AkBAEedsVGGdUgwAgoIkEA>: sieve: Execution of script /var/spool/mail/SpamAndBcc.sieve failed with unsuccessful implicit keep
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net dovecot[807537]: lmtp(807581): Disconnect from local: Logged out (state=READY)
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/lmtp[807520]: B898A7F9E7C: to=<james@domain.net>, relay=mail.domain.net[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=2.9, delays=2.9/0/0.02/0.01, dsn=5.2.2, status=bounced (host mail.domain.net[private/dovecot-lmtp] said: 552 5.2.2 <james@domain.net> Quota exceeded (mailbox for user is full) (in reply to end of DATA command))
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net dovecot[807537]: lmtp(archive)<807580><tDXGEOdsVGGcUgwAgoIkEA>: sieve: msgid=<c650f17b-5d64-dac4-1760-96e8ccc0e455@domain.net>: failed to store into mailbox 'INBOX': Quota exceeded (mailbox for user is full)
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net dovecot[807537]: lmtp(archive)<807580><tDXGEOdsVGGcUgwAgoIkEA>: sieve: Execution of script /var/spool/mail/SpamAndBcc.sieve failed with unsuccessful implicit keep
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net dovecot[807537]: lmtp(807580): Disconnect from local: Logged out (state=READY)
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/lmtp[807518]: B898A7F9E7C: to=<archive@domain.net>, relay=mail.domain.net[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=2.9, delays=2.9/0/0.01/0.02, dsn=5.2.2, status=bounced (host mail.domain.net[private/dovecot-lmtp] said: 552 5.2.2 <archive@domain.net> Quota exceeded (mailbox for user is full) (in reply to end of DATA command))
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/cleanup[807516]: 4C21A7F9E81: message-id=<20210929134055.4C21A7F9E81@mail.domain.net>
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/bounce[807514]: B898A7F9E7C: sender non-delivery notification: 4C21A7F9E81
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/qmgr[807513]: 4C21A7F9E81: from=<>, size=3725, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/cleanup[807516]: 4E1987F9E83: message-id=<20210929134055.4E1987F9E83@mail.domain.net>
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net dovecot[807537]: lmtp(807581): Connect from local
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/bounce[807514]: B898A7F9E7C: postmaster non-delivery notification: 4E1987F9E83
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/qmgr[807513]: 4E1987F9E83: from=<double-bounce@domain.net>, size=3735, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/qmgr[807513]: B898A7F9E7C: removed
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net dovecot[807537]: lmtp(807580): Connect from local
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net dovecot[807537]: lmtp(james)<807580><4MiYE+dsVGGcUgwAgoIkEA>: sieve: msgid=<20210929134055.4E1987F9E83@mail.domain.net>: failed to store into mailbox 'INBOX': Quota exceeded (mailbox for user is full)
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net dovecot[807537]: lmtp(james)<807580><4MiYE+dsVGGcUgwAgoIkEA>: sieve: Execution of script /var/spool/mail/SpamAndBcc.sieve failed with unsuccessful implicit keep
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net dovecot[807537]: lmtp(807580): Disconnect from local: Logged out (state=READY)
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/lmtp[807518]: 4E1987F9E83: to=<james@domain.net>, orig_to=<postmaster>, relay=mail.domain.net[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=5.2.2, status=bounced (host mail.domain.net[private/dovecot-lmtp] said: 552 5.2.2 <james@domain.net> Quota exceeded (mailbox for user is full) (in reply to end of DATA command))
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/cleanup[807516]: 564EF7F9E85: message-id=<20210929134055.564EF7F9E85@mail.domain.net>
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/bounce[807514]: 4E1987F9E83: sender non-delivery notification: 564EF7F9E85
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/qmgr[807513]: 564EF7F9E85: from=<>, size=5838, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/qmgr[807513]: 564EF7F9E85: to=<double-bounce@domain.net>, relay=none, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (undeliverable postmaster notification discarded)
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/qmgr[807513]: 564EF7F9E85: removed
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/cleanup[807516]: 582FA7F9E86: message-id=<20210929134055.582FA7F9E86@mail.domain.net>
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/bounce[807514]: 4E1987F9E83: postmaster non-delivery notification: 582FA7F9E86
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/qmgr[807513]: 582FA7F9E86: from=<double-bounce@domain.net>, size=2273, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/qmgr[807513]: 4E1987F9E83: removed
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net dovecot[807537]: lmtp(807580): Connect from local
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net dovecot[807537]: lmtp(james)<807580><ANfqFedsVGGcUgwAgoIkEA>: sieve: msgid=<20210929134055.582FA7F9E86@mail.domain.net>: failed to store into mailbox 'INBOX': Quota exceeded (mailbox for user is full)
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net dovecot[807537]: lmtp(james)<807580><ANfqFedsVGGcUgwAgoIkEA>: sieve: Execution of script /var/spool/mail/SpamAndBcc.sieve failed with unsuccessful implicit keep
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net dovecot[807537]: lmtp(807580): Disconnect from local: Logged out (state=READY)
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net dovecot[807537]: lmtp(comm)<807581><YGYhE+dsVGGdUgwAgoIkEA>: sieve: msgid=<20210929134055.4C21A7F9E81@mail.domain.net>: stored mail into mailbox 'INBOX'
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/lmtp[807520]: 4C21A7F9E81: to=<comm@domain.net>, relay=mail.domain.net[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=0.06, delays=0.01/0/0/0.05, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 <comm@domain.net> YGYhE+dsVGGdUgwAgoIkEA Saved)
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net dovecot[807537]: lmtp(807581): Disconnect from local: Logged out (state=READY)
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/qmgr[807513]: 4C21A7F9E81: removed
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/lmtp[807518]: 582FA7F9E86: to=<james@domain.net>, orig_to=<postmaster>, relay=mail.domain.net[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=0.01, delays=0/0/0/0, dsn=5.2.2, status=bounced (host mail.domain.net[private/dovecot-lmtp] said: 552 5.2.2 <james@domain.net> Quota exceeded (mailbox for user is full) (in reply to end of DATA command))
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/cleanup[807516]: 5C8387F9E88: message-id=<20210929134055.5C8387F9E88@mail.domain.net>
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/bounce[807514]: 582FA7F9E86: sender non-delivery notification: 5C8387F9E88
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/qmgr[807513]: 5C8387F9E88: from=<>, size=4376, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/qmgr[807513]: 5C8387F9E88: to=<double-bounce@domain.net>, relay=none, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (undeliverable postmaster notification discarded)
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/qmgr[807513]: 5C8387F9E88: removed
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/cleanup[807601]: 5E7F37F9E89: message-id=<20210929134055.5E7F37F9E89@mail.domain.net>
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/bounce[807514]: 582FA7F9E86: postmaster non-delivery notification: 5E7F37F9E89
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/qmgr[807513]: 5E7F37F9E89: from=<double-bounce@domain.net>, size=2273, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/qmgr[807513]: 582FA7F9E86: removed
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net dovecot[807537]: lmtp(807581): Connect from local
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net dovecot[807537]: lmtp(james)<807581><YBy8F+dsVGGdUgwAgoIkEA>: sieve: msgid=<20210929134055.5E7F37F9E89@mail.domain.net>: failed to store into mailbox 'INBOX': Quota exceeded (mailbox for user is full)
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net dovecot[807537]: lmtp(james)<807581><YBy8F+dsVGGdUgwAgoIkEA>: sieve: Execution of script /var/spool/mail/SpamAndBcc.sieve failed with unsuccessful implicit keep
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net dovecot[807537]: lmtp(807581): Disconnect from local: Logged out (state=READY)
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/lmtp[807520]: 5E7F37F9E89: to=<james@domain.net>, orig_to=<postmaster>, relay=mail.domain.net[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=0.02, delays=0.01/0/0/0.01, dsn=5.2.2, status=bounced (host mail.domain.net[private/dovecot-lmtp] said: 552 5.2.2 <james@domain.net> Quota exceeded (mailbox for user is full) (in reply to end of DATA command))
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/cleanup[807516]: 644BE7F9E8B: message-id=<20210929134055.644BE7F9E8B@mail.domain.net>
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/bounce[807514]: 5E7F37F9E89: sender non-delivery notification: 644BE7F9E8B
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/qmgr[807513]: 644BE7F9E8B: from=<>, size=4376, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/qmgr[807513]: 644BE7F9E8B: to=<double-bounce@domain.net>, relay=none, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (undeliverable postmaster notification discarded)
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/qmgr[807513]: 644BE7F9E8B: removed
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/cleanup[807601]: 65F957F9E8C: message-id=<20210929134055.65F957F9E8C@mail.domain.net>
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/bounce[807514]: 5E7F37F9E89: postmaster non-delivery notification: 65F957F9E8C
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/qmgr[807513]: 65F957F9E8C: from=<double-bounce@domain.net>, size=2273, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
sept. 29 15:40:55 mail.domain.net postfix/qmgr[807513]: 5E7F37F9E89: removed
```

And it keeps going the same way until I restart postfix & dovecot.
It looks like the system geneates an email from postmaster to james, and since james's mailbox is full it keeps looping.
Any clue on a parameter to fix this ?

Thanks in advance.